# How do construct ForEach into map in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

I have sample `JSON`  in form of

```js
   var sample=[{"id":200,"children":[{"value":300,"type":"SINGLE"},{"value":400,"type":"CLASSIC"},{"value":600,"type":"DUAL"}]},{"id":300,"children":[{"value":500,"type":"TRIO"},{"value":600,"type":"MUSICAL"},{"value":700,"type":"UMBRELA"}]}]

var result = [];
sample.forEach(function(e){
  let obj = {}
  obj.id=e.id
  obj['somekey']=e.children[0].value
  obj['someanotherkey']=e.children[1].type
  result.push(obj);
})
console.log(result)
```

How do i can achieve same using map `es-6`

Comment: Where is `result` declared?

Comment: Why you're not interested in the other Array objects, but just the `[0]`th one?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i need all of them but i will do once i know how to do on 1st

Answer (score 0):

```js
var sample=[{"id":200,"children":[{"value":300,"type":"SINGLE"},{"value":400,"type":"CLASSIC"},{"value":600,"type":"DUAL"}]},{"id":300,"children":[{"value":500,"type":"TRIO"},{"value":600,"type":"MUSICAL"},{"value":700,"type":"UMBRELA"}]}]
var output = sample.map(({ id, children }) => ({ id, ...children[0] }));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score -1):

[`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns an array, so you must set up a variable to hold that result. Then, within the loop, you use `return` to effectively push items into the array.

```js
var sample=[{"id":200,"children":[{"value":300,"type":"SINGLE"},{"value":400,"type":"CLASSIC"},{"value":600,"type":"DUAL"}]},{"id":300,"children":[{"value":500,"type":"TRIO"},{"value":600,"type":"MUSICAL"},{"value":700,"type":"UMBRELA"}]}];

let result = sample.map(function(e){
  let obj = {}
  obj.id=e.id;
  obj['value']=e.children[0].value;
  obj['type']=e.children[0].type
  return obj;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to be able to chose the `children` index:

```
const getDataChild = (a, i) => a.map(({id, children:ch}) => ({id, ...ch[i]}));

console.log(getDataChild(sample, 0)); // where 0 is the desired index
```